# Spark-shell add jar import class not correctly

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark, jar, hadoop-yarn

something really magical happened when I test my jar in Spark-shell.

First,
I run

```
spark-shell --master yarn --jars myTestJar.jar
```

to initialize spark-shell, and then import class defined in myTestJar.jar

```
import myTest.myclass
val test = new myclass
....
```

to test my programs.

Since I keep changing my code, so I start spark-shell and end it multiple times.(I'm sure each time it's assigned with different application id)

Then, this time I run

```
spark-shell --master yarn
```

And type

```
import myTest.myclass
val test = new myclass
```

It works!!??? And I'm pretty sure myclass is in myTestJar.jar only, no other duplicated class name. So it makes troubles for testing and tuning my class. Any idea about why it happens? Thanks!!!

BTW, I'm using 2.1.0.3.

Comment: Are you sure that `myTestJar.jar` isn't located somewhere that is already on the class path?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt that's a great point! Do you know how to check it?